# How do I use xpath on nodes with a prefix but without a namespace?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, namespaces, nokogiri

I have an XML file that I need to parse. I have no control over the format of the file and cannot change it.

The file makes use of a prefix (call it `a`), but it doesn't define a namespace for that prefix anywhere. I can't seem to use `xpath` to query for nodes with the `a` namespace.

Here's the contents of the xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<a:root>
  <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff2</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff3</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff4</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff5</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff6</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff7</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff8</a:thing>
  <a:thing>stuff9</a:thing>
</a:root>
```

I am using Nokogiri to query the document:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('text.xml'))
things = doc.xpath('//a:thing')
```

The fails giving the following error:

```
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: //a:thing
```

From my research, I found out that I could specify the namespace for the prefix in the `xpath` method:

```
things = doc.xpath('//a:thing', a: 'nobody knows')
```

This returns an empty array.

What would be the best way for me to get the nodes that I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the namespace is not properly defined in the XML document. As a result, Nokogiri sees the node names as being "a:root" instead of "a" being a namespace and "root" being the node name:

```rb
xml = %Q{
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <a:root>
      <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
      <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
    </a:root>
}
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc.at_xpath('*').node_name
#=> "a:root"
puts doc.at_xpath('*').namespace
#=> ""
```

**Solution 1 - Specify node name with colon**

One solution is to search for nodes with the name "a:thing". You cannot do `//a:thing` since the XPath will treat the "a" as a namespace. You can get around this by doing `//*[name()="a:thing"]`:

```rb
xml = %Q{
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <a:root>
      <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
      <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
    </a:root>
}
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
things = doc.xpath('//*[name()="a:thing"]')
puts things
#=> <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
#=> <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
```

**Solution 2 - Modify the XML document to define the namespace**

An alternative solution is to modify the XML file that you get to properly define the namespace. The document will then behave with namespaces as expected:

```rb
xml = %Q{
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <a:root>
      <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
      <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
    </a:root>
}
xml.gsub!('<a:root>', '<a:root xmlns:a="foo">')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
things = doc.xpath('//a:thing')
puts things
#=> <a:thing>stuff0</a:thing>
#=> <a:thing>stuff1</a:thing>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I run `doc.xpath('//thing')` and I get an empty array back. Could it be a problem with the version? I'm running ruby 2.0.0p247 with nokogiri 1.6.0.

Comment: Apparently things have changed between Nokogiri 1.5.8 and 1.6.0. The above script works in 1.5.8, but not in 1.6.0 (using Ruby 1.9.3).

Comment: I updated the answer to have 2 solutions that work in Nokogiri 1.6.0.

Comment: Solution 2 fits my needs the best. Is there a way to be able to modify the document through Nokogiri after it's loaded?

Comment: Do you mean to add the namespace? I do not believe so. I sort of recall people mentioning that Nokogiri only registers the namespaces when the document is parsed.

Comment: @JustinKo I do like your answer always, as I see you answers are always well arranged!!