# Avoiding Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: ERROR: Undefined namespace prefix

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, parsexml

I get the error "Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: ERROR: Undefined namespace prefix" when I do this:

```
 doc.search('//text()[not(ancestor::w:delText]')
```

Based on this answer: [How do I use xpath on nodes with a prefix but without a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004081/how-do-i-use-xpath-on-nodes-with-a-prefix-but-without-a-namespace)

```
*[name()="w:delText"]
```

can sort of solve the problem. But how do I do something similar like this to avoid the namespace error:

```
doc.search('//text()[not(ancestor::*[name()="w:delText"]')
```

Comment: please post an example of your XML and what exactly you're trying to target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by editing the XML file and adding the namespaces in the root. Here is an example:

```
  temp = Nokogiri::XML(@document_xml)
  temp.root['xmlns:w'] = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"      
  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(temp.to_xml(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_XML))
```